# Sublime Text build system on Ubuntu: Cannot chain pkill command regardless of success

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sublimetext, build-system

I'm trying to first kill a running process

```
pkill -f "java.*MySketch"
```

then run it again

```
processing-java --sketch="~/MySketch" --output="~/MySketch/build-tmp" --run --force
```

However on first build the process isn't running so `pkill` finds nothing. I want the build system to skip this error and move on to executing `processing-java`.

**Processing.sublime-build**

```
  "linux": {
    // Close old sketch on build
    "shell_cmd": "pkill -f \"java.*$file_base_name\" ; processing-java --sketch=\"$file_path\" --output=$file_path/build-tmp --run --force"
  },
```

I've tried using `;` and appending `|| true` at the end of the pkill command. Also tried `pgrep -f "java.*MySketch" | xargs kill > /dev/null 2>&1` but it's still not working in Sublime Text. Moving everything to a `build.sh` script also doesn't work. It works in the terminal.
In Sublime it says `Finished in 0.3s with exit code -15`. So I guess instead of failing to find a process and doing nothing, the termination signal (SIGTERM) ends my whole `shell_cmd`?! SIGKILL (`pkill -9 -f ...`) too.

Only thing I've managed to get working in Sublime Text is a blanket case killing all java processes, `pkill java ; processing-java bla bla bla`

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** pkill is killing itself first because my regex pattern is not smart enough to match the real `java` process only.

Comment: You can for example use "cmd" instead of ""shell_cmd" and link it to a shell script (.sh) file with multiple instructions, ifs, loops, etc. `{
    "cmd": ["/path/script.sh"]
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this build system was killing itself first, because its own commandline matched `java.*MySketch`.

**Solution:** Replaced `\"java.*$file_base_name\"` with `\"java.*$file_path\\$\"`

**Details:** Looked at the commandline of the process I want to kill and saw that it ended with `--sketch-path=~/Sketchbook/MySketch`, whereas the build system's commandline ends with `--force`. Used `(blabla)$` regex for matching the end of the string. Because of the Sublime Build system, had to escape it with extreme prejudice... `\\$`.